# SpringApplicationConfiguration not found: Erroneous spring-boot-starter-test content?

Tags: maven, testing, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Getting a compilation error in Maven:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/prototypes/demo-sse-spring-boot-master/src/test/java/com/cedric/demo/sse/SseDemoApplicationTests.java:[6,37] package org.springframework.boot.test does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/TITAN/demo-sse-spring-boot-master/src/test/java/com/cedric/demo/sse/SseDemoApplicationTests.java:[10,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringApplicationConfiguration
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Maven repo seems to have the jar present:

[image]

howerever that jar doesn't have any compiled classes inside it. only META-INF dir:

[image]

Is that by design?  Where do I get the jar containing **SpringApplicationConfiguration** class to make Maven happy?

Here's the relevant parts of my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`spring-boot-starter-test`, like all the other Spring Boot starters, is really just a pom that pulls in a number of other dependencies transitively. It only has a jar to keep some build systems that don't like pom-only dependencies happy.

It looks like you have upgraded an application from Spring Boot 1.4 to Spring Boot 1.5. Spring Boot 1.5 removes a number of classes that were deprecated in 1.4, including `org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

I would recommend dropping back to Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE and fixing all of the deprecation warnings. You should then be able to upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE without difficulty.

Comment: Yes, that trick worked for me, thanks.  Could you point  me to a comprehensive description of how this Maven setup works which enables it to pull the dependencies without a need to list them, not quite clear on why 1.5.1.RELEASE couldn't have done it, is it a major version on which the decision was made to discontinue the support of deprecated items?  Thank you again.

Answer (score 103):

In your release the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotation no longer exists. The new annotations are :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(classes = YourApplicationMainClass.class)

@WebAppConfiguration
```

Comment: This should have been the chosen answer

Answer (score 23):

As the error is due to the upgrade of Spring Boot from 1.4 to 1.5, its important to note (from below) that several new classes that are introduced in 1.4 deprecated some of the existing classes leading way to finally getting removed in 1.5. The details of such can be found at: [Spring boot release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes)

Quoted from website (edited):

Additionally, Spring Boot 1.4 (and above) attempts to rationalize and simplify the various ways that a Spring Boot test can be run. You should migrate the following to use the new @SpringBootTest annotation:

> *From **`@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=MyConfig.class)`** to **`@SpringBootTest(classes=MyConfig.class)`***
>
> From **`@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyConfig.class,  loader=SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)`** to
>   **`@SpringBootTest(classes=MyConfig.class)`**
>
> From **`@IntegrationTest`** to
>   **`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.NONE)`**
>
> From **`@IntegrationTest`** with **`@WebAppConfiguration`** to
>   **`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT) (or RANDOM_PORT)`**
>
> From **`@WebIntegrationTest`** to
>   **`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT) (or RANDOM_PORT)`**
>
> Tip Whilst migrating tests you may also want to replace any
>   **`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`** declarations with Spring 4.3’s
>   more readable **`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`**.

Comment: Accordingly: `@SpringBootTest(classes = YourApplicationMainClass.class)` and `@WebIntegrationTest` together from earlier versions translates to a single statement in `@SpringBootTest(classes = YourApplicationMainClass.class, webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)`